Why does GARCH-SVM output identical predictions for conditional volatility?
I'm using the SVR-GARCH model to predict conditional volatility, as described in the book Machine Learning for Financial Risk Management with Python: Algorithms for Modeling Risk by Abdullah Karasan.
I’ve encountered an issue where my code sometimes produces the same repeated value for the conditional volatility across the entire forecasting horizon. I understand that the initial parameter values are randomized, but I am confused about why, in most cases, the prediction results in a constant value throughout the forecast period.
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from scipy.stats import uniform as sp_rand
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Select assets
stock_name = ['AAPL']
end_date = datetime.today()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(days = 365 * 25)

# Download the prices
prices = yf.download(
    stock_name,
    start = start_date,
    end = end_date,
    interval = '1d',
)['Adj Close']
prices = prices.dropna()
stock_name = ['Apple']
prices = prices.rename(stock_name[0], inplace = True)

# Log returns
returns = np.log(np.array(prices)[1:] / np.array(prices)[:-1])

# Forecasting horizon
H = 146

returns_series = pd.Series(returns)
realized_vol = returns_series.rolling(5).std()
realized_vol = pd.DataFrame(realized_vol)
realized_vol.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

returns_svm = pd.DataFrame(returns ** 2)

X = pd.concat([realized_vol, returns_svm], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
X = X[4:].copy()
X = X.reset_index()
X.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)

realized_vol = realized_vol.dropna().reset_index()
realized_vol.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)

conditional_volatility = pd.DataFrame(index=prices.index[-H:], columns=['SVM Linear','SVM RBF','SVM Poly'])

para_grid = {'gamma': sp_rand(0.1, 1), 'C': sp_rand(0.1, 10), 'epsilon': sp_rand(0.1, 1)}

svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear')
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(svr_lin, para_grid)
clf.fit(X[:-H], realized_vol.iloc[1:-(H-1)].values.reshape(-1,))
predict_svr_lin = clf.predict(X[-H:])
conditional_volatility['SVM Linear'] = predict_svr_lin

svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf')
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(svr_rbf, para_grid)
clf.fit(X[:-H], realized_vol.iloc[1:-(H-1)].values.reshape(-1,))
predict_svr_rbf = clf.predict(X[-H:])
conditional_volatility['SVM RBF'] = predict_svr_rbf

svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly')
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(svr_poly, para_grid)
clf.fit(X[:-H], realized_vol.iloc[1:-(H-1)].values.reshape(-1,))
predict_svr_poly = clf.predict(X[-H:])
conditional_volatility['SVM Poly'] = predict_svr_poly

print(conditional_volatility)

Output:
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
            SVM Linear   SVM RBF  SVM Poly
Date                                      
2024-01-09    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204
2024-01-10    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204
2024-01-11    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204
2024-01-12    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204
2024-01-16    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204
...                ...       ...       ...
2024-08-01    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204
2024-08-02    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204
2024-08-05    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204
2024-08-06    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204
2024-08-07    0.168156  0.168156  0.138204

[146 rows x 3 columns]

Why this might be happening and how to address it?

Could you please add in the question the error that you are experiencing?

I have added the output of the code. It's random, so it is not always the same. Sometimes it makes sense (more or less). Sometimes, as in this case, it does not.

the issue is with your epsilon values. According to the SVR manual:

epsilon - Epsilon in the epsilon-SVR model. It specifies the
epsilon-tube within which no penalty is associated in the training
loss function with points predicted within a distance epsilon from the
actual value. Must be non-negative.

Thus with high epsilon (epsilon much greater than volatility) you won't give any penalties for bad predictions.
Let's check how your data is distributed:
print(np.quantile(realized_vol, q = [0,0.01,0.05,0.5,0.95, 0.99,1]))
# [0.00075101 0.00375092 0.0058641  0.04780242 0.06916338 0.33556116]

Basically in the beginning of the dataset volatility is very low and it is much greater in later periods.
Anyway, if you allow epsilon to be close to 1 (as in your code) you don't give penalty to any of the volatility points, because they all far below 1.
The fix is to change parameter grid to smth like this:
para_grid = {'gamma': sp_rand(0.1, 1), 
             'C': sp_rand(0.1, 10), 
             'epsilon': sp_rand(0.001, 0.01)
            }

or to multiply volatility by a high constant (after all volatility is a percentage):
para_grid = {'gamma': sp_rand(0.1, 1), 
             'C': sp_rand(0.1, 10), 
             'epsilon': sp_rand(0.1, 1)
             }

realized_vol = realized_vol * 100


Thank you so much! Multiplying volatility by 100 seems the best option
